# Application asn1 is used in release app-release name and cannot be excluded

Tags: erlang, rebar

This error occurs then I try to generate release:

```
ERROR: generate failed while processing rel: {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,"Application asn1 is used in release \"app-release\" and cannot be excluded"}}
```

I've got the following code in my `retool.config`

```
{lib_dirs, ["../../", "../deps"]}
{app, asn1, [{incl_cond, exclude}]}
```

But this error still occurs.

P.S. I'm just trying to generate release with external dependencies (such as mochiweb and sqlite).

Answer (score 2):

You are excluding the `asn1` application in your reltool config but there is a dependency to it as you error message says. Either change it to:

```
{app, asn1, [{incl_cond, include}]}
```

or you might get away with removing the line completely.

I know the `reltool` documentation is tedious but worth the [read](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/reltool.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the problem is still there. Neither including  asn1 nor deleting this line helped me. And the error message don't even change for my surprise.

Comment: Do you know which application depends on `asn1`?

Comment: Nope. This probably can be mochiweb or sqlite lib. Should I include `asn1` in this applications?